# Javascript Invoking function out of order?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

I'm coding up a tool that grabs data from an SQL database that translates the result of a query (a number) to a colour that is passed to a javascript variable.

In short I'm using ajax to open my php code to query the database and returning it.

The problem I've been having is that I can't get the javascript working quite as inteded. For debugging purposes I added in a few 'window.alert's to understand whats going on.

So how I am wanting the code to run is that of:

1. pickColour is invoked by the 'Try it' button and passes 'B03' as
   arg1
2. getCount is invoked inside pickColour and sends off the xml
   request and returns with the number after parsing it from the
   xmlhttp.responseText string.
3. It returns this number to the variable temp in pickColour
4. A series of if/else statements chooses the colour

But from how my code is running is that:

1. pickColour is invoked correctly
2. The window alerts occur in this order, window.alert(arg1),
   window.alert(temp), window.alert(color), window.alert(count). I
   would have thought seeing as window.alert(count) is in the
   getCount() function it surely would be called second in line instead
   of last, and because of this it is not returning the count ready for
   the window.alert(temp).

I know I could maybe just merge the two functions into one to make it work however I am intrigued as to why this doesn't work now.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

var count;
var temp;

function getCount(arg1) {

    if (arg1 == "") 
    {
        document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    else 
    { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 

        else  
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 

        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var temp = xmlhttp.responseText; //This returns the <doctype HTML>

                var test = temp.split("<body>"); //Splitting the string into an array so that the number is the first in the 2nd array

                count = parseInt(test[1]); //Grabbing the Int and setting it back to count

                window.alert(count); //shows 192 correctly. Runs 4th

                return count; //returning count to variable temp in the 'pickColour' function
            }
        }

       xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+arg1,true);
       xmlhttp.send();

    }
}

function pickColour(arg1)
{
    window.alert(arg1); //Runs first
    var temp = getCount(arg1); 
    window.alert(temp); //shows as undefined... - Runs 2nd

    var colour;

    if (temp <= 200 &&  temp >= 100)
    {
        color = '#0f70d2';
    }
    else if (temp < 100)
    {
        color = '#3bff00';
    }
    else if (temp <= 400 && temp >= 500)
    {
        color = '#ff0000';
    }
    else
    {
        color = '#000000';
    }

    window.alert(color); //Runs 3rd
    return color;
}



</script>


<form>
<select name="buildings" onchange="getCount(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a building:</option>
  <option value="B01">Building 1</option>
  <option value="B22">Building 22</option>
  <option value="B03">Building 3</option>
  <option value="B44">Building 44</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="Count"><b></b></div>

<button onclick=pickColour("B03")>Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous, so the result wont be available until an undertermined time later.

Comment: Ahh right that would make sense (this is my first time with anything to do with AJAX), knowing that I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter of `xmlhttp.open` is the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29) value. Since the code sets it true, the request is asynchronous: `getCount` starts the xmlHttpRequest operation but returns before it completes. Only when the operation does complete (some time later) is xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` called and the alert of count produced.

Comment: Cheers for explaining how it all works, I should have read up on how exactly it all works before hand! many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Jaromanda X mentioned, AJAX/XMLHttpRequest calls are asynchronous, so you will have to rework your code a little.

The code the checks the range of the returned count and determines the colour (the `if...else if` block) needs to be put inside the `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)` block.

Comment: Thanks for that, definitely helps explain whats going on!

Comment: No problem. Mark one of the answers as correct if you can to help out others looking for a solution.  :)